# Calculate percentage of a value using stream

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, percentage, collectors

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the percentage of a specific value in a list when using `stream`.

My object `getTag` can take value `G`or `Y` and I want to calculate the percentage of `G:s` in the list. The other object is `getDateTime` which is of the form `1946-01-12`.

I have the condition `filter(weather -> !weather.getDateTime().isAfter(dateTo) && !weather.getDateTime().isBefore(dateFrom))` because I only want the percentage between two dates that are user input.

So each DateTime value corresponds to either `G` or `Y`. I used `Collectors.counting()` to calculate the frequency of both `G` and `Y`, but how can I get the percentage?

```
Map<String, Long> percentage = weatherData.stream()
        .filter(weather -> !weather.getDateTime().isAfter(dateTo) && !weather.getDateTime().isBefore(dateFrom))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Weather::getTag, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you map the item you care about ("G") to 1, and everything else to 0, the average value is the percentage of "G" in the stream.

```
double pctG = list.stream()
    .mapToInt(obj -> obj.getTag().equals("G") ? 1 : 0)
    .summaryStatistics()
    .getAverage();
```

With Java 13, you can use the `teeing()` collector to count the elements by tag, *and* the total number of elements after filtering, finishing by dividing the group count by the total:

```
Map<String, Double> fractions = weatherData.stream()
        .filter(...)
        .collect(
            Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Weather::getTag, Collectors.counting()),
                Collectors.counting(),
                YourClass::scale));
```

Where the `scale()` function divides each group by the total:

```
static <T> Map<T, Double> scale(Map<? extends T, Long> counts, long total) {
    return counts.entrySet().stream().
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), ((double) e.getValue()) / total));
}
```

Comment: what would be `items.size()` that is being passed down as value? there is nothing called `items` here.

Comment: @Naman Sorry that was a typo. It’s supposed to be the size of the list, but now I see that doesn’t account for filtering...

Comment: The problem with the edit is that the scaling factor is an incorrect value passed further. (because of the `filter`). In short, there is no straight forward way to deal with keeping a count of the elements before the terminal operation apart from a SummaryStatistics in my knowledge..

Comment: @Naman Exactly, that’s what I meant with my comment. I will update.

Comment: In terms of (approximate) correctness, you might want to split it in two operations such as counting in  `List<Weather> validDates = weatherData.stream().filter(weather -> !weather.getDateTime().isAfter(dateTo) && !weather.getDateTime().isBefore(dateFrom)).collect(Collectors.toList());` and then evaluating the percentage as in `Map<LocalDate, Double> countByDate = validDates.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Weather::getDateTime, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(),  a -> (double) a / validDates.size())));`